# Pressure activated gel cooling pads for dogs: what are the physics behind them?

Tags: thermodynamics

I recently bought a pressure activated gel cooling pad for my dog.

(comparable product: [https://www.amazon.com/Hugs-Pet-Products-Pressure-Activated/dp/B00C65TXO6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C65TXO6))

The mat is filled with a gel that noticeably cools down, when light pressure is applied.
Now, in my understanding compression should lead to an increase in temperature.

Unfortunately I was not able to find any sources that explain the effect involved in pressure induced cooling of the gel inside the cooling pad. I could also not find any further information about the gel itself that is inside the cooling mat.

Can someone explain to me how such a cooling pad works and what the physics are behind it? I would also be happy if someone could point me towards any literature on this topic.

Comment: Does the compressed gel feel any colder than an adjacent chunk of metal? If not, it sounds like the mechanism could simply involve improved thermal contact to a thermally conductive material.

Comment: That is a very good point. It does actually feel comparable to an adjacent piece of metal. However everything I can find explicitly mentions that the gel is pressure activated.

Comment: [Note that all thermal conduction between objects is pressure activated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_contact_conductance#Contact_pressure). But it does seem that Carl Witthoft has a more accurate description of the actual mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might expect (well, if you have a background in chemistry or materials science anyway),  here's the [basic cycle](https://edkeepingitcoolblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/cooling-gel-pillow/)

> The gel in a cooling pad is water-based with a polymer. Polymer is an
> activated chemical that changes properties when pressure-activated.
> When it’s activated it pulls the heat from the body. It is based on
> endothermology which means a chemical change that is accompanied by an
> absorption of heat.
>
> How does Polymer Activate? When contact or pressure is removed and
> there is no longer heat to absorb, the pad re-activates. It typically
> takes 20- 30 minutes depending upon the environment. … To reactivate
> the cooling pad, simply remove from pressure and let it sit in a cool
> place for approximately 30 minutes.”

Comment: In other words, it's a dry puddle of water which doesn't evaporate which is both good and bad.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with the thermodynamics of polymers, but what exactly happens, that makes the polymer able to absorb heat by applying pressure? 
Is it actually a form of second order phase transition, as the above comment implies?
Also what is endothermology? A quick search did only show that term in the context of other cooling gel products.